# how to autoplay tiny-slider after the video is finished?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tiny-slider

I am using tns-slider pluging and have 3 slides (2 photos and 1 video)

```
<div class='tiny-slider'>
   <div class='slide slide1'>
    <div class='video-slide'>
        <video id="desk" loop autoplay muted>
            <source src="/videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='slide slide2'>
    <div class='slide-overlay'>
      <div class='slide-title'>Slide two</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='slide slide3'>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/700/500/tech" alt="">
  </div>  
</div>
```

and the settings:

```
const slider = tns({
    'items' => 1,
    'controls' => false,
    'loop' => true,
    'autoplay' => true,
    'lazyload' => true,
    'autoplayTimeout' => 4000
  });
});
```

The slider will autoplay .... but I want to autoplay only when the video is finished.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use `autoplay: true` in your slider (which you already have) and stop it right away with `slider.pause();`. This is necessary to be able to start autoplay later.

Then you listen to the `ended` Event and execute the `play()` function on the slider.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    const slider = ...

    document.getElementById('desk').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        slider.play();
    }
</script>
```